# не выполняется скрипт через exec

Tags: php

у меня есть скрипт (a.php) в котором параллельно запускается другой (b.php) командой exec("/usr/bin/php /full/path/to/b.php >/dev/null 2>/dev/null &");

при запуске в браузере a.php b.php выполняется, а при запуске через терминал — нет.

в моем случае роль a.php играет скрипт для long-poll бота, а b.php долгий скрипт, который нужно выполнить параллельно. он загружает картинку в вк и записывает ссылку на неё в бд. проект на виртуальном хостинге.

что делать?

Comment: php cli установлен?

Comment: полные пути до исполняемого файла `php` пробовали указать? например `/usr/bin/php /path/to/script.php`

Comment: @andrey-mihalev да, проблема осталась

Answer (score 0):

проблема решилась с переходом на vps